# traffic source for a question

Tags: discussion

Recently a question of mine got an unusual surge in upvotes, I guess I may have been linked from some high visibility blog or something like that.

Is there any way to know the traffic sources for a question?

Answer (score 3):

[It was posted on Reddit r/programming:](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/1z2p8b/python_magic_decompile_generator_bytecode_rebuild/)

[image]

It is still on the front page at #9.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the most accurate, but you can search for link backs on google like this.

Also, I'm not sure which question you're referring to, so I used your most viewed question as an example.

[image]

https://www.google.com/#q=link:+http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F4533884%2Fis-using-readlines-in-python-bad-code

1. Just copy the URL of the question you want to know about.
2. Go to Google
3. Type **link:**
4. Paste the URL after link: (space)
5. Click search

I'm guessing you got a lot of views for your most viewed question from the bitcoin result.